# TemplateNotFound: theme_base.html

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to set up a webpage, and one of my html files begins with {% extends "theme_base.html" %}. When I try to run the program, I get an error message saying "TemplateDoesNotExist" for `theme_base.html`. I don't think this is a file that I have to create. Is there something I need to install to access this html file? I've already got `pinax_theme_bootstrap` installed. I thought that that was what I needed, but the error is still there.

Comment: do you assign the `theme_base.html` file inside the templates folder?

Answer (score 0):

Usually with Django, websites have a base theme, which other pages use to display content so you don't have to recode things like the header and footer. This is the basis of most front-end frameworks.

The question is, why does your HTML file extend a base template that doesn't exist? It sounds like you're trying to alter pieces of a project without the underlying files to the project.

The django docs are really great, and if you're new to django going through their quick tutorials will help you substantially:

https://www.djangoproject.com/start/